# __proto__ chain in JS, property is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am confused with the proto chain in javascript. In the following code, only A has the property name while B and C don't. And the `__proto__` are set for b and c, correctly I believe. Why is the output of name property for b and c are "undefined"? How do I make them print out "Tom"?

```
function A(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

function B() {
    A.call(this, this.name);

}

function C() {
    B.call(this);
}

var a = new A("Tom");
var b = new B();
var c = new C();
b.__proto__  = a;
c.__proto__  = b;

console.log("c.name = " + c.name); // undefined
console.log("b.name = " + b.name); // undefined
console.log("a.name = " + a.name); // Tom
```

Comment: Offtopic hint: [Read up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) on how to properly do class inheritance in JavaScript. Using `__proto__` and explicitly naming ancestor inside constructor/methods is not a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the following code, only A has the property name while B and C don't

That's where you are mistaken. Every `c` and `b` also have a `name` property.

> Why is the output of name property for b and c are "undefined"?

Because of

```
function B() {
    A.call(this, this.name);
}
```

Since you are calling `A.call(...)`, the new `B` instance will have **its own** `name` property, which is set to the value of `this.name`, which is `undefined` at this point. I.e. `A.call(this, this.name);` is equivalent to `this.name = undefined;`.

If you do `console.dir(b)`, you will see that the own `name` property shadows the one of its prototype:

[image]

Similar for `c`.

> How do I make them print out "Tom"?

You could remove the `X.call(...)` calls:

```
function A(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
function B() {}
function C() {}
```